# javascript not firing on this web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

on this  [page](http://uat.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/dementia.aspx)  the javascript function set cookie is not firing on 'OK' click on the top of the page in the cookie bar. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Please be more specific and don't let us do all the searching and debugging.

Comment: All i m trying to do when user clicks on the ok button in the cookie bar it should hide and its not hiding.

Comment: Since you don't quite understand what I mean by 'being more specific', I suggest you read the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working. I have a cookie set. You're simply not using the correct logic somewhere on the backend to hide the bar.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Now on page load I have added a script to test if the cookie is present then hide the bar.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is setting the cookie. See my screen shot. You're just not reading it correctly to hide the cookies-bar layer.

[image: Screen shot of your cookie]